# Remove bottom whitespace in Vuetify v-carousel-item

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, whitespace

In my VuetifyJS `v-carousel-item` I have an image, title and subtitle as shown below. But I am getting a lot whitespace at the bottom. I have set background color for `v-carousel-item` to Purple and we can see a lot of it in the picture.

[image]

I have tried removing the content of the carousel item and this is what I get.

[image]

I have tried setting the height, removing padding and margins but nothing has worked, below is my code

```
          <v-carousel
            cycle
            :show-arrows="false"
            style="background-color: pink"
          >
            <v-carousel-item
              v-for="item in carouselItems"
              :key="item.id"
              style="background-color: purple; height: 800px"
              class="pb-0 mb-0"
            >
              <- Content for Carousel item->
            </v-carousel-item>
          </v-carousel>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I tried adding ``<v-carousel height=10px />`` in your code and the height is now 10px. Have you tried adding height to the ``v-carousel`` tag? 
Not as a style properties. The height itself.

Answer (score 1):

As the vuetify document mentioned, the default value for `height` of `v-carousel` is 500. Therefore, if you do not give it a value, the default height of the `v-carousel` would be 500.

Therefore, I suggest using pictures with same heights in the carousel and set the `height` according to them. Like this:

```
  <v-carousel
    cycle
    :show-arrows="false"
    style="background-color: pink"
    height='120px'
  >
    <v-carousel-item
      style="background-color: purple; height: 70px"
      class="pb-0 mb-0"
    >
      <- Content for Carousel item->
    </v-carousel-item>
    <v-carousel-item
      style="background-color: purple; height: 70px"
      class="pb-0 mb-0"
    >
      <- Content for Carousel item->
    </v-carousel-item>
    <v-carousel-item
      style="background-color: purple; height: 70px"
      class="pb-0 mb-0"
    >
      <- Content for Carousel item->
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it very easily.
Just put v-carousel contents in a parent div with container class as below :

```
<div class="container">
    <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item>
            your codes
        </v-carousel-item> 
    </v-carousel>
</div>
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a lot of the examples on the documentation wrongly use a `v-row` component to wrap the contents inside of the `v-carousel-item`.

```html
  <v-carousel v-model="model">
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(color, i) in colors"
      :key="color"
    >
      <v-sheet
        :color="color"
        height="100%"
        tile
      >
        <!-- This v-row will get you the undesired empty space at the bottom of the carousel -->
        <v-row
          class="fill-height"
          align="center"
          justify="center"
        >
          <div class="text-h2">
            Slide {{ i + 1 }}
          </div>
        </v-row>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>
```

You only need to replace the `v-row` with a div:

```html
  <v-carousel v-model="model">
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(color, i) in colors"
      :key="color"
    >
      <v-sheet
        :color="color"
        height="100%"
        tile
      >
        <!-- This div will get rid of the undesired empty space at the bottom of the carousel -->
        <div class="d-flex fill-height align-center justify-center">
          <div class="text-h2">
            Slide {{ i + 1 }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>
```